# How can I distinguish sub-categories with the same name?

Tags: categorization

My portal has the following categories structure:

- => Name of Magazine
- => Year
- => Month
- => Name of section (Study, Law, Opinion, etc.)

Trouble is the 'Name of section' is identical for many magazines so often the typists confuses the appropriate magazine, year and month of publication and selects the wrong one.

Is there an alternative method for categorizing such a system?

Comment: The question is currently very hard to answer imo, because it is not very clear why typists are confused. Is there a possibility to post a screenshot of some sort to make things more clear?

Comment: Confusing. Are these section one inside other... or they are all high level category. Can you give 2-3 real data for us to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a limited knowledge about the situation so my answer may be not to the point.

There is nothing wrong with the same names of sections. **There is apparently something wrong with the way that users select the category.**

I think you should consider presenting the categories in the appropriate context. One magazine can have the same years, months and sections as the other as long as you display the related information. Consider using [breadcrumbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_%28navigation%29) or displaying the information in a way that leaves no doubt about the greater categories above.

Comment: My first thoughts were that this would lend itself better to a filter/search than a hierarchical navigation. This is quite common with online stores.

Comment: @Bartosz-Rakowski this idea is useful, however is some packages, like Wordpress, the categories may appear shuffled so their full context is not apparent